# Is this loop redundant?

Tags: sqlite

The three tables of interest are:

- Event, containing various details of, eg, the berlin marathon
- Result, containing various fields including user's race time and a FK to an Event, and
- Goal, with a FK to the Event the user would like to run, a field for the time they'd like to run it in, and eventually a FK to the Race at which the user achieved their goal.

Obviously, the Event of the Race where the user achieved their goal has to be the Event of the Goal. But not all Goal's have been achieved -- some may never be.

Is this bad design? Can anybody suggest a better way of modelling this problem?  I'm using sqlite in a django project.

Comment: Loop? Where's the loop?

Comment: A Goal has two different ways to get to Event, creating a loop of relations.

Comment: So this database does *not* store information about missed goals?

Comment: Missed goals are not important for this project.

Comment: Would it be better to check the 'achieved'-status of a goal in a query instead of inputting it as a field?  That is, for each goal, check every result to see if it satisfies the goal time.  This seems very labourious for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your Event table is OK.

But your Goal Table design messed up the proposed event and the actual achieved event.

I think Result Table can be merged with Goal table into a new Result table.

Since one user may want to run multiple events. In your new Result table, it should be like:

```
UserID EventID TimeProposed ActualTimeUsed Achieved
1      1        1 hour      1.1 hour       No
1      2        1.5 hour    1.2 hour       Yes
```

So the loop you mentioned is removed since each row has only one event. (The UserID and EventID remains to be the FK to the other two tables.)

The Achived column can be updated using a query to decide ActualTimeUsed<=TimeProposed.

Comment: Unfortunately there's is no way to check the achieved status against the actual race results.  This still leaves open the possibility of inconsistencies.

Comment: Since your "achieved" column is a query generated field. I modified my answer.